# OutputPath is set to be bin\x86\release, but shown as obj\x86\release when using MSBuild

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, nant

In my .csproj file (C# project file) [`OutputPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-properties) is set as in the following:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86' ">
  <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
  <OutputPath>bin\x86\Release\</OutputPath>
  ....
</PropertyGroup>
```

In my NAnt script, I have this:

```
<msbuild project="${demo.solution}">
  <property name="Configuration" value="release"/>

  <property name="OutputPath" value="${output.dir}"/>
  <property name="Platform" value="x86"/>
</msbuild>
```

Why is the log showing that the DemoProject.dll is copied from obj\x86\release?

> ....
>
> [msbuild] Project "Demo.sln" (1) is building "DemoProjec1.vbproj" (3) on node 0 (default targets).
>
> [msbuild] Copying file from "obj\x86\Release\DemoProjec1.dll" to ${output.dir}\DemoProjec1.dll".
>
> [msbuild] DemoProjec1 -> ${output.dir}\DemoProjec1.dll
>
> [msbuild] Done Building Project "DemoProjec1.vbproj" (default targets).

....

Somehow the DemoProject.dll from `obj` is different in size compared to DemoProject.dll from `bin`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`obj\x86\release` is the [`IntermediateOutputPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-properties) for the release configuration.

Your project is compiled in the intermediate directory and then the result file is copied to your output directory. In your NAnt file you override the `OutputPath` to `${output.dir}`, so your file is copied from `obj\x86\release` to `${output.dir}`.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply madgnome. I see where I got it wrong. However I still don't understand how can the size of the output file be different from obj and from bin. It happens to some projects and some particular output files randomly.